# Hello World Angular CLI as Measured by Lighthouse(Why slow and enormous?)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lighthouse

**Do optimizations need to be applied to the Angular CLI Hello World or is this a valid "performance" result?**

In applying Lighthouse to our live angular 4 project, we compared to the Angular CLI Hello World.

From console:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve --prod
```

In Chrome -> F12 -> Audits -> Run Lighthouse.

- Performance is 39/100.
- First Meaningful Paint is 15,250ms
- Perceptual Speed Index: 15,248 (target: < 1,250)
- Has enormous network payloads: Total size was 2,453 KB (target: < 1,600 KB)

**Update 1**

Thx to @Moshe, using:

```
ng serve --prod --build-optimizer
```

Gave the following:
 - Performance is 96/100.
 - First Meaningful Paint is 2,040ms
 - Perceptual Speed Index: 2,054 (target: < 1,250); Grade of 92/100

Ultimately had a difficult time forming a singular, concise question for this.  I understand  `ng serve`  is not for production use, even with ags..  But this allows my to test on my localhost before publishing.

Comment: Do you really mean `serve` and not `build`? I may well be wrong, but given that `ng serve` uses `webpack-dev-server` behind the scenes and won't have all the final production ready optimisations such as aot, this doesn't seem like a fair test. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274

Comment: @Kirk, thx for input, was told ng serve --prod would include aot, or be the same as ng serve --aot=true.  All the same found answer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
ng serve --prod --build-optimizer
```

build-optimizer flag is a new tree-shaking method built on top of the CLI.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was wanting a way to run Lighthouse locally before hosting. I understand ng serve isnt for production use, but this lets me compare a baseline to what we have now. Thx

Comment: "As of 5.0.0, production builds created with the CLI will now apply the build optimizer by default." https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced

Answer (score 3):

`ng serve` is not meant to be completely optimized, it is meant to be a quick display of your project for testing.  If you want the optimized version you have to run `ng build --prod` to generate the files, and then you have to host those files.  Do a test on that and it will run much quicker.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Totally agree with you.  However @Moshe gave a solution that allows for testing in a scenario that correlates to putting together a Hello World and testing it.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a PWA, with `ng new <your app's name> --service-worker`, the best Lighthouse audit result comes from the following:

1. Build the app with optimizations

   ng build --prod --build-optimizer
2. Host it somewhere with https to take advantage of HTTP2. [For example for firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying) (you need an account):

   `npm install -g firebase-tools`

   `firebase login`

And then at your root directory (the one above src and dist usually)

```
firebase init
```

There, select

> Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

Add it to a firebase project, and when you are asked about the public directory

> What do you want to use as your public directory?

type `dist`.

Afterwards

```
firebase deploy
```

3. Visit the url that the previous command returns, and audit there.

---

**The result that you're getting from auditing the output of `ng serve`
(or `npm start`), is not representative, as it focuses on compilation
speed and ease of debugging.**

Comment: best answer, thanks